# Unable to connect to the remote server - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Running into the subject issue trying to update the proxies with nswag... funny enough, the app that this came with is preconfigured to use a specific port for that service, but I don't see anything on that port using `netstat -ano` in the command line. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: which port are you using?

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: I can turn off my firewall and still have the problem, and I can see which port is preconfigured, but it doesn't seem to be being used.

Answer (score 0):

Before running nswag/refresh.bat the host needs to be up and running.

To start host, copy the below lines and create a batch file (bat).

```
CD "D:\Github\MySolution\src\MyProject.Web.Host"

SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:22742
dotnet run
```

Comment: I do not appear to have a "web.host" directory... would the host still be running on my machine even if my machine is only acting as a front-end while connecting to a CORE server for the backend?

Comment: @J.King How are you running the ASP.NET Core server?

Comment: The core server is being run on company server, using Azure services, but I'm connecting my computer to that service and developing locally, then pushing those changes to the Azure server after testing.

Answer (score 0):

It was some settings on the server (so a corporate guy told me), so nothing on my end, but thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: yeah I suspected such kinda network issue but people can only guess with the parameters you provide them.